# Killing orphan Dask workers

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

How can I remove Dask workers which have been orphaned? I have tried the usual approaches such as pkill and kill -9 but the workers won't die.

Comment: Could you give us some more information? OS? Is there anything specific on your end that you think are producing the orphans?

Comment: Hi Niklas, the OS is linux mint. And I say these are orphans because the process that was used to create them was killed but yet, the workers created didn't die. Specifically, here's an example of the process used to create the workers: dask-worker ip_address_here:8786 --nprocs 10 --nthreads 10 &